# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib - Error in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, hackintosh

I was working on Xcode 7 beta with Swift in a Mac mini (running Yosemite) Due to poor performance i installed Yosemite on my PC (like Hackintosh). And i copied the "xcode 7 beta.app" from 'applications' folder to my new pc's Yosemite.

Note: This question is already asked in stack overflow. But none of the solutions worked for me.

When i try to run the app in to my iPad i got an error like this. But no problem while running in emulator

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/80F87502-B264-4BF3-8200-4B9A69C99189/Hi Gijo.app/Hi Gijo
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/80F87502-B264-4BF3-8200-4B9A69C99189/Hi Gijo.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: mmap() errno=1 validating first page of '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/80F87502-B264-4BF3-8200-4B9A69C99189/Hi Gijo.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'
(lldb)
```

I searched a lot and find to method to fix it. But none of them worked for me.

1. 'Embedded content contains swift code' = Yes.
2. adding '@executable_path/Frameworks' to runpath.

Can someone pls tell me how can i fix this? Will reinstalling Yosemite/Xcode fix this? (I only have the .app file of xcode) Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved. I downloaded the new xcode 7 gm speed .dmg file from apple beta developers and installed. Now everything works fine

Comment: Do you have a link?  Is that the new beta version, you just updated xcode?